# Use Windows cmd to set PYTHONPATH for embedded Python interpreter

Tags: python, cmd, pythonpath

I am using Windows batch as the entrance for users to run a Python script for some simple automation requests. I have referred to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3701730/22279546). Assuming I have used another batch to copy the **embedded** Python to `%userprofile%`. Code as below:

```
pushd "\\Share\Share Drive\share place"
set oldir=%cd%

cd "%userprofile%\python311"
set PYTHONPATH="%userprofile%\python311";"%userprofile%\python311\Lib";"%oldir%"
call python "%oldir%\scripts_prd\%script_name%.py" %1 "%ori%"
```

However, this `set PYTHONPATH=...` doesn't work here. The script can be access but any other modules in the %oldir% cannot be accessed, reporting error 'Module not found'.

Just want to know if the PYTHONPATH should be set by different way for **embedded** Python interpreter?

---

Update 1:

Thanks to Tim, I've deleted the `call`.
I've written a script including `print(sys.path)` and it returns the below values (userprofile replaced):

```
%userprofile%\python311\python311.zip;
%userprofile%\python311;
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages;
%userprofile%\python311\Lib\site-packages;
%userprofile%\python311\Lib\site-packages\win32;
%userprofile%\python311\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib;
%userprofile%\python311\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

Apparently `set PYTHONPATH` doesn't work in this **embedded** python interpreter.

I also showed `os.getcwd` and it shows **the network folder where the python scripts are stored**, and a workaround `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` can be used as workaround. But I believe there must be some better solution.

---

Update 2:

Thanks to Mofi. I've change the code into

```
pushd "\\Share\Share Drive\share place"
set "oldir=%cd%"
...
set PYTHONPATH="%userprofile%\python311;%userprofile%\python311\Lib;%oldir%"
```

which works perfectly in the standard (installed) python interpreter. But it still doesn't work in **embedded interpreter**.

But thanks to all, I have find the solution and will update very soon.

Comment: You don't need `call` for Python.  That's only used to invoke other batch files.  Have you done `set PYTHONPATH` to see exactly what the variable is?  Have you tried a script that just does `print(sys.path)` to see what it is getting?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tims and Mofi, I have updated the batch code but found it is still not useful for the **embedded Python**. Luckily, I've found the reason and solution.

---

**Conclusion**: PYTHONPATH is not supported by embedded Python interpreter. This can be proved from the [issue28245](https://bugs.python.org/issue28245) on the python community. It is just **impossible** to use environment variable in an embedded Python interpreter.

**Solution**: `python[version]._pth` file in the embedded python interpreter. Edit `python311._pth` (this is for my interpreter) to hard code the directory. This works for either a local place or a share folder. Pls refer to the [document](https://docs.python.org/3.11/using/windows.html#finding-modules).

Technically, I can hard-code the `python311._pth` and use Windows batch to copy it into the embedded interpreter directory each time. For example:

```
copy python311._pth "%userprofile%\python311"
```

This works very well on my side.